# js Symbol() usage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

looking through a polyfill I found Symbols type used like this :

```
if (window.Symbol) {
  obj = {cached: Symbol(),    /****/ };
}

/* and is used */
 obj.cached = [] // which overrides Symbol(),
```

I'm new to `Symbol()` in JS, but from what I know it should be used for making unique object keys that avoid collision, an so should be used more or less like:

```
var obj = {}, cached;

if (window.Symbol) {
    cached = Symbol();
    obj[cached] = null;
}
/* an then used */
 obj[cached] = [ /*****/ ];
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: That is the primary purpose of a Symbol. But really `Symbol` is just a unique, *immutable* primitive (like `Object.freeze({})`) and its purpose here may be just to ensure that the `cached` value is not modified. Your second example is actually invalid because `cached` is block-scoped to the `if` statement

Comment: @RGraham in the first example the cached property can be overwritten , I can't understand how it can be used as a value;

Comment: It can be overwritten, but not *modified*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your example, but in general `Symbol()` is "something guaranteed to be unique". It can be used in a way similar to this:

```
var cached = Symbol();

var state = {obj: cached };

// code that can change state.obj in arbitrary ways

if (state.obj === cached) 
  console.log("still cached");
```

On the other side, one could have used `cached = Object()` with the same effect... so maybe it's not the best example.

Comment: I found the key, the object was actually being used to populate property names in an elements proto, thanks